# What does Object.Function()()(param,param) mean?

Tags: c++

I am reading some C++ code that was designed and written by a lot of programmers that I would consider better than myself. I encountered this line:

```
rawReceive.Signal()()(*this, completedData);
```

What is the triple set of brackets mean? I made a small test program, and that doesn't compile. Is there some trick I don't understand, or is this gibberish?

Thanks.

Comment: A function call can return a function (which can then be called etc) and/or `operator()` has been overridden in a strange way.

Comment: It's impossible to know without knowing the type of `rawReceive.Signal()`, `*this`, and `completedData`. Presumably `Signal` returns a class that has overloaded `operator()`, and the return value of _that_ is in turn something that's defined `operator()` that takes two arguments.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. Of course it makes sense! Even though I wouldn't have written like this for readability's sake. I was dumbfounded by Signal() not even being defined in the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of mysteries are solved one step at a time:

```
rawReceive.Signal()
```

This calls the `Signal()` method of whatever `rawReceive` is.

```
                   ()
```

`Signal()` must be returning some unspecified callable object. That is: an object that itself implements an `operator()` overload. Perhaps it's a `std::function`. The `operator()` overload gets invoked. It takes no parameters.

```
                     (*this, completedData);
```

The first `operator()` overload returns another callable object. This one's `operator()` takes two parameters, and they are provided thusly.

You will have to look at the program where this came from in order to determine what actual objects each one of these functions call, step by step. Just follow the breadcrumbs.

Comment: We can't see the declarations, so it is possible that the  various calls could be returning function pointers rather than function objects.